# The **distribution** of number of tosses until getting $k$ consecutive heads

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Assume a fair coin. The expectation of the number of tosses $X$ until getting $k$ consecutive heads is well known.

What is the *PMF* of $X$? ($k$ might not be $2$) I searched high and low but there is no satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $n>k$. To get $P(X=n)$ recursively we note that your string must begin with $H^iT$ for $i\in \{0, \cdots, k-1\}$.  Then, after that initial block of length $i+1$ you are back where you started.  Thus $$P(X=n)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac 1{2^{i+1}}P(X=n-i-1)$$

This provides a handy way to compute $P(X=n)$, though it falls well short of a convenient analytic expression.  I'm not sure there's any reason to expect such an expression to exist.

Comment: Thanks! In reality we usually expect $k$ to be concrete though.

Comment: Note:  I just edited to repair an off-by-one error (my personal specialty).  Of course the block $H^iT$ has length $i+1$, not length $i$.

Comment: For any particular $k$ you can solve this "explicitly". It's just a recurrence with constant coefficients.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  True...but for large $k$ you will, I expect, have to fall back on numerical methods to get the roots of the characteristic polynomial and I doubt the resulting formula will be that much easier to work with than the recursion.  Depends on what you are trying to do, of course.